# How to write a SQLITE trigger to calculate the sum when the database is updated or inserted?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, triggers

I am working with SQLITE. I am trying to create trigger.
The code for creating my table is:

```
CREATE TABLE SEM1 (
USN   VARCHAR (10) REFERENCES studentDet (USN) ON DELETE CASCADE
                   UNIQUE
                   PRIMARY KEY
                   NOT NULL,
SUB1E INTEGER (2),
SUB2E INTEGER (2),
SUB3E INTEGER (2),
SUB4E INTEGER (2),
SUB5E INTEGER (2),
SUB6E INTEGER (2),
SUB7E INTEGER (2),
SUB8E INTEGER (2),
TOTAL INTEGER (4)
```

);

TRIGGER NAME: CALCTOTAL1

When: AFTER

Action:UPDATE

ON Table: SEM1

Scope: For Each Row

Code:

```
UPDATE TOTAL SET TOTAL=SUM(INSERTED.SUB1E,INSERTED.SUB2E,INSERTED.SUB3E,INSERTED.SUB4E,INSERTED.SUB5E,INSERTED.SUB6E,INSERTED.SUB7E,INSERTED.SUB8E);
```

And I am getting error:

```
[22:59:26] Error while executing SQL query on database 'RAS': wrong number of arguments to function SUM()
```

UPDATE 1:

```
UPDATE TOTAL SET TOTAL=(INSERTED.SUB1E+INSERTED.SUB2E+INSERTED.SUB3E+INSERTED.SUB4E+INSERTED.SUB5E+INSERTED.SUB6E+INSERTED.SUB7E+INSERTED.SUB8E) WHERE USN=NEW.USN;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` is an aggregate function, i.e., it works on multiple rows.
To add up multiple values from the same row, just use `+`.

And you must specify the table name after the UPDATE.

And SQLite has no `INSERTED`; the values of the new row are available with `NEW`. But in this case, you can just use the values from the table.

And you should restrict the UPDATE to the row that just got updated:

```
UPDATE SEM1
SET TOTAL = SUB1E + SUB2E + SUB3E + SUB4E + SUB5E + SUB6E + SUB7E + SUB8E
WHERE USN = NEW.USN;
```

Comment: Now I am getting new error :-                                                                                         [17:24:46] Error while executing SQL query on database 'RAS': no such table: main.TOTAL